How to determine directx capabilities of my graphics card?
Playing video games via Steam with proton/wine and on the family's older PC sometimes we run into the error that directX 11 is not supported by our hardware. I can easily set what dx version to use via launch options, but it's a bit of trial and error and guesswork. I can't figure out how to determine the highest DX level my graphics card supports. Is there a command for this?

You need to look up the card specs. DirectX is a bird from Windows. In Ubuntu there is OpenGL and Vulkan.

That's what i have been doing so far... even though we use opengl, with steam games that are 'windows only' we use the proton (wine) compatibility layer and still have to (on the older box) adjust the settings to restrict the directX version... easy enough... however if there was a way to see this info via command line it would be super useful...

sudo lshw -C display on Linux will display all things GPU related. But you can forget about DX. Proton uses WineD3D (old) or DXVK (new). Is there more to it?

Yea, I have used that, of course not dx info... what I end up doing is setting  the launch options for the game to something like -dxlevel 90 and I can get it to work after trial and error... I was just hoping to take the guesswork out... I guess (lol) not :/
